# 'Upload files or drop files' to 'Upload file or drop file'

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightninginput, fileupload

How can I change the **'Upload files or drop files'** text to **'Upload file or drop file'**.
When I am allowing **single file upload** in lightning-input component.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish it with **Static Resources** and some **lightning
style classes**.

Create the **.css** file with next content and upload it to **Static Resources** :

```css
/* remove the "or drop files" label from the right of the lightning:input type file */
.slds-file-selector__dropzone .slds-file-selector__text {
    font-size: 0 !important;
}

/* insert the text "or drop file" into the label */
.slds-file-selector__dropzone .slds-file-selector__text:after {
    content: 'or drop file' !important;
    font-size: .8125rem !important;
    color: rgba(27, 82, 151, 1.0) !important;
}

/* remove the "Upload Files" text from the button of the lightning:input type file */
.slds-file-selector__dropzone .slds-file-selector__button {
    font-size: 0 !important;
}

/* insert the text "Upload File" into the button of the lightning:input type file */
.slds-file-selector__dropzone .slds-file-selector__button:after {
    content: 'Upload File' !important;
    font-size: .8125rem !important;
    color: rgba(27, 82, 151, 1.0) !important;
}
```

Then in your **LWC** import the **Static Resources** and the `lightning-platform-resource-loader` (link - [Platform Resource Loader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-resource-loader/documentation)  ):

```javascript
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import testFileUpload from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/testFileUpload';
 
export default class TestFileUpload extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        Promise.all([
            loadStyle(this, testFileUpload + '/testFileUpload.css')
        ]).then(() => {
            console.log('Upload success')
        }).catch( (error) => {
            console.error(error);
        })
    }
}
```

My HTML file (link : [File Upload](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-file-upload/documentation)):

```html
<template>
    <div class="card">
        <div>
            <lightning-file-upload
                label=""
                name="fileUploader"
                accept={acceptedFormats}
                record-id={myRecordId}
                onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}
                multiple
            ></lightning-file-upload>
        </div>
        <div>
            <lightning-input 
                type="file" 
                label="Attachments"
                variant="label-hidden"
            ></lightning-input>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And the result :

[image]

So you can see it works for both `<lightning-input type="file">` and for `<lightning-file-upload>`.

**Note :**
You can change the `content` property in your **.css** file to what you **need** !

Comment: Can you help me with how to upload the css file to static resources?

Comment: @AkshitaGupta create css file on your desktop, => create .zip file with .css file inside => go to Setup => static resources => new => and upload the .zip file which you created.